# Terms of a sum in a R expression

Tags: r, evaluation

Given a R expression which represents a sum of terms like

`expr <- expression(a + b * c + d + e * f)`

I would like to retrieve the set of all the terms of the sum as a list
of names or expressions. So in the example, the elements would be:  `a`, `b * c`, `d` and `e * f`.

The following comes from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300717/terms-of-a-sum-in-a-r-expression/53300817#comment93482228_53300817).

> The tems could themselves contain a `+` operator as in
>
> ```
> expression(a + b * c + d + e * (f + g))
> ```
>
> so we need some understanding of the R language.

Is there a simple way to proceed e.g., using `call_tree` of the **pryr** package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to crawl the parse tree:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  if (is.call(x)) y <- as.list(x) else return(x)

  #stop crawling if not a call to `+`
  if (y[[1]] != quote(`+`)) return(x) 

  y <- lapply(y, foo)

  return(y[-1]) #omit `+` symbol
}

expr1 <- expression(a + b * c + d + e * f)
unlist(foo(expr1[[1]]))
#[[1]]
#a
#
#[[2]]
#b * c
#
#[[3]]
#d
#
#[[4]]
#e * f


expr2 <- expression(a + b * c + d + e * (f + g))
unlist(foo(expr2[[1]]))
#[[1]]
#a
#
#[[2]]
#b * c
#
#[[3]]
#d
#
#[[4]]
#e * (f + g)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try recursively parsing the expression:

```
getTerms <- function(e, x = list()) {
  if (is.symbol(e)) c(e, x)
  else if (identical(e[[1]], as.name("+"))) Recall(e[[2]], c(e[[3]], x))
  else c(e, x)
}

expr <- expression(a + b * c + d + e * (f + g))
getTerms(expr[[1]])
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
a

[[2]]
b * c

[[3]]
d

[[4]]
e * (f + g)
```