# Extract information inside parentheses of formula

Tags: r, regex, expression, formula, extract

I am writing an R package, in which users write formulas that look like this:

```
outcome ~ var1 + var2 + mm(id, mmc(var3, var4), mmw(pupils^exp(teacher*b)))
```

The right-hand side includes variable names and the element mm(), which itself contains a variable name (id) and the elements mmc() and mmw().

I would like to separate mm(), mmc(), mmw(), i.e. end up with variables

```
mm  = id, mmc(var3, var4), mmw(pupils^exp(teacher*b))
mmc = var3, var4
mmw = pupils^exp(teacher*b)
```

Is my only option to parse the formula as characters and then use regex to separate the elements or are there ways to handle this more elegantly since it is a formula?

I have tried

```
all.vars
all.names
```

but they break up mmw() too much since mmw() typically contains nonlinear functional relationships

Comment: does this help http://www.cookbook-r.com/Formulas/Extracting_components_from_a_formula/ ?

Comment: The problem with using indices is that the order might be unexpected:
**outcome ~ mm(id, mmc(var3, var4), mmw(pupils^exp(teacher*b))) + var1 + var2**. Is there a way to get the right index for mm(), mmc(), and mmw()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Using `getTerms` from [Terms of a sum in a R expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300717/terms-of-a-sum-in-a-r-expression/53300817#53300817) we can directly parse the formula without using regular expressions. First we get the terms `tt` and then form `mm` which is the term having more than one element.  From that extract the others.  No packages are used.

```
fo <- outcome ~ var1 + var2 + mm(id, mmc(var3, var4), mmw(pupils^exp(teacher * b)))

tt <- getTerms(fo[[3]])
mm <- as.list(tt[lengths(tt) > 1][[1]])[-1]
mmc <- as.list(mm[[2]][-1])
mmw <- as.list(mm[[3]][-1])
```

giving:

```
> mm
[[1]]
id

[[2]]
mmc(var3, var4)

[[3]]
mmw(pupils^exp(teacher * b))

> mmc
[[1]]
var3

[[2]]
var4

> mmw
[[1]]
pupils^exp(teacher * b)
```

**2)** Alternately we might incorporate the processing right into `getTerms` giving `getMs` as follows:

```
getMs <- function(e, x = list()) {
  if (length(e) == 1) x
  else if (identical(e[[1]], as.name("+")))
    c( Recall(e[[2]], x), Recall(e[[3]], x) )
  else if (as.character(e[[1]]) %in% c("mm", "mmw", "mmc")) {
      for(i in 2:length(e)) x <- Recall(e[[i]], x)
      c(setNames(list(as.list(e[-1])), as.character(e[[1]])), x)
  } else x
}
res <- getMs(fo[[3]])
str(res)
```

giving:

```
List of 3
 $ mm :List of 3
  ..$ : symbol id
  ..$ : language mmc(var3, var4)
  ..$ : language mmw(pupils^exp(teacher * b))
 $ mmw:List of 1
  ..$ : language pupils^exp(teacher * b)
 $ mmc:List of 2
  ..$ : symbol var3
  ..$ : symbol var4
```