# Remove multiple instances with a regex expression, but not the text in between instances

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr, gsubfn

In long passages using `bookdown`, I have inserted numerous images. Having combined the passages into a single character string (in a data frame) I want to remove the markdown text associated with inserting images, but not any text in between those inserted images.  Here is a toy example.

```
text.string <- "writing ![Stairway scene](/media/ClothesFairLady.jpg) writing to keep ![Second scene](/media/attire.jpg) more writing"

str_remove_all(string = text.string, pattern = "!\\[.+\\)")
[1] "writing  more writing"
```

The regex expression doesn't stop at the first closed parenthesis, it continues until the last one and deletes the "writing to keep" in between.

I tried to apply [String manipulation in R: remove specific pattern in multiple places without removing text in between instances of the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455830/string-manipulation-in-r-remove-specific-pattern-in-multiple-places-without-rem), which uses `gsubfn` and `gsub` but was unable to get the solutions to work.

Please point me in the right direction to solve this problem of a regex removal of designated strings, but not the characters in between the strings.  I would prefer a `stringr` solution, but whatever works.  Thank you

Comment: Another option is `str_replace_all(text.string, "!.*?\\)", "")`, because you really only need to look for what you don't want since that seems to follow a solid pattern. That does leave you with double whitespace between substrings just like your example; this will make it a single whitespace: `str_replace_all(text.string, "!.*?\\) ", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the following regex

```
"!\\[[^\\)]+\\)"
```

alternatively you can also use this:

```
"!\\[.*?\\)"
```

both solution offer a **lazy** match rather than a **greedy** one, which is the key to your question

Comment: A word about how the use of the character class making the evaluation lazy in the first case would be a useful expansion, if I read the distinction correctly, as against `*?` in the second case.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Lazy stops at the first instance, whereas greedy gobbles on and on.  The .*? could thus be read as "remove all characters until you reach a, or the first )" ?

Comment: @lawyeR yes, the .*? will from left to right keep adding characters to it's match until it has found a ")". Afterwards it will look again for the next "![" and repeat the process. Lazy matches can be expensive tho, hence I also gave the first option (negated class). The negated class solution simply matches all characters that are not a ")" and keep everything from ")" to the next "![", making it a more efficient solution if you have a lot of data

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the following solution too:

```
gsub("!\\[[^][]*\\]\\([^()]*\\)", "", text.string)

[1] "writing  writing to keep  more writing"
```