# R substitute(), to substitute values in expression, is adding unnecessary quotes

Tags: r, expression, substitution, r-formula

I am trying to update a formula for a linear model in R, based on names of variables that I have stored in an array. I am using `substitute(`) for that and the code is as follows.

```
var = 'a'
covar = c('b', 'c')
covar = paste(c(var, covar), collapse = ' + ')
formula = substitute(condition ~ (1|subject) + v, list(v = as.name(covar)))
print(formula)
```

Output

```
condition ~ (1 | subject) + `a + b + c`
```

**How do I remove the extra `` around a + b + c?**

If I don't concatenate with paste, then it works, but I need those extra variables...

```
var = 'a'
formula = substitute(condition ~ (1|subject) + v, list(v = as.name(var)))
print(formula)
```

Output

```
condition ~ (1 | subject) + a
```

Both var and covar are char type.

**Another solution that lets iteratively change v in formula that could also work**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood what you are doing, but the following seems to work:

```
form  <- 'condition ~ (1|subject) + v'
var   <- 'a'
covar <- c('b', 'c')
```

Then combine with paste and turn to formula directly:

```
covar <- paste(var, paste(covar, collapse=" + "), sep=" + ")
form  <- formula(paste(form, covar, sep=" + "))
```

Output:

```
condition ~ (1 | subject) + v + a + b + c
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `v` is a term by itself (which is the case in the question) and the inputs shown in the Note at the end.  Then here are two approaches.

**1) update** Use `reformulate` to create the formula `~ . - v + a + b + c` and update the input formula with it.

```
update(fo, reformulate(c(". - v", var, covar)))
## condition ~ (1 | subject) + a + b + c
```

**2) getTerms** Another approach is to decompose the formula into terms using `getTerms` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300717/terms-of-a-sum-in-a-r-expression/53300817#53300817), remove `v`, append `var` and `covar` and `reformulate` it back into a formula:

```
reformulate(c(setdiff(sapply(getTerms(fo[[3]]), format), "v"), var, covar), fo[[2]])
## condition ~ (1 | subject) + a + b + c
```

### Note

The inputs are assumed to be:

```
var <- 'a'
covar <- c('b', 'c')
fo <- condition ~ (1 | subject) + v
```

Comment: I was using 'v' as a placeholder in the specific case of the substitute() function. Overall this solution also works for the problem I have in hand with formulas for linear models.

Comment: If it is good enough just to add on `var` and `covar` you wouldn't really need a placeholder in which case it would be sufficient to use: `fo2 <- condition ~ (1 | Subject); update(fo2, reformulate(c(".", var, covar)))`

Comment: Also if we can assume that the input is the character vector `x <- c("condition", "(1 | Subject)", var, covar)` rather than a formula then the desired formula is just `reformulate(x[-1], x[1])` .